# Non-existent package gazebo in ROS hydro

Tags: ros, gazebo, ros-hydro, rosmake, roshydro

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi All,

I am using rosmake a package in ROS hydro, but it gives me below errors:

```
 [rosbuild] Building package labrob_hummingbird_controller
  Failed to invoke /opt/ros/hydro/bin/rospack deps-manifests labrob_hummingbird_controller
  [rospack] Error: package/stack 'labrob_hummingbird_controller' depends on non-existent package 'gazebo' and rosdep claims that it is not a system dependency. Check the ROS_PACKAGE_PATH or try calling 'rosdep update'
  
  
  CMake Error at /opt/ros/hydro/share/ros/core/rosbuild/public.cmake:129 (message):
    
  
    Failed to invoke rospack to get compile flags for package
    'labrob_hummingbird_controller'.  Look above for errors from rospack
    itself.  Aborting.  Please fix the broken dependency!
```

It seems that there is no gazebo dependency any more in ROS hydro. Does anyone know which dependency I should use to replace gazebo? The manifest.xml of the stack 'labrob_hummingbird_controller'  can be found below:

```
<package>
  <description brief="HummingBirdController">

     HummingBirdController

  </description>
  <author>Lorenzo Rosa</author>
  <license>BSD</license>
  <review status="unreviewed" notes=""/>
  <url>http://ros.org/wiki/HummingBirdController</url>
  <depend package="gazebo"/>
  <depend package="geometry_msgs"/>
  <depend package="gazebo_plugins"/>
  <depend package="ar_pose"/>
  <!--depend package="ipc_bridge"/-->

  <export>
    <gazebo plugin_path="${prefix}/lib" />
  </export>

</package>
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/131606/non-existent-package-gazebo-in-ros-hydro/) by [Sendoh](https://answers.ros.org/users/6040/sendoh/) on ROS Answers with karma: 85 on 2014-02-20

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

ROS hydro + Gazebo have a new integration package now

I hope this helps you http://gazebosim.org/wiki/Tutorials/1.9/Overview_of_new_ROS_integration

---

Originally posted by [waldezjr](https://answers.ros.org/users/14036/waldezjr/) with karma: 16 on 2014-03-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0